# Getting ParserError eventhough semicolon is there

Tags: solidity

I am trying to make my own ERC-token on the ethereum network.

However, when I try to compile at Solidity I get this error:

*browser/ballot.sol:121:9: ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'Identifier'
        name = "UFDADollar";                           // Set the name for display purposes
        ^*

Here is the code:

```
function ERC20Token(
    ) {
    balances[msg.sender] = 1986000;               // Give the creator all initial tokens (100000 for example)
    totalSupply = 1986000                        // Update total supply (100000 for example)
    name = "UFDADollar";                           // Set the name for display purposes
    decimals = 0 ;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = "UFDA";                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}
```

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 3):

As the error indicates, there's a semicolon missing at the end of the line `totalSupply = 1986000`.